# Removing firewalld passthrough rules

Tags: centos7, firewalld

This one is causing me confusion. Add a permanent passthrough rule: -

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-passthrough ipv4 -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 65533 -j DROP
success
```

Issue a reload so the rule takes effect

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Verify rule is now active

```
# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-passthroughs
ipv4 -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 65533 -j DROP
```

Remove the rule

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --remove-passthrough ipv4 -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 65533 -j DROP
success
```

Reload. Rule is still active!?

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-passthroughs
ipv4 -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 65533 -j DROP
```

The only way I can find to remove it is to do a full a restart of firewalld

```
systemctl restart firewalld
```

This is on CentOS 7 with firewalld-0.6.3-12. Surely this can't be designed behaviour?